# Saving tree-like structure

Tags: perl, persistence

I have following tree-like structure where each level is represented by separate class:

```
Book ------ Page ------ Line
     1    n      1    n
```

Each class has a property that holds all its members (e/g/ `Book::pages`, as array of blessed refs), some properties specific to the level (e.g. `Book::author`) as well as some methods to add/remove its members.

Now I want to save/load all the data to/from a single file.  It's not going to be a relational DB (most probably YAML will be used), so basically what I need to get at some point is something like:

```
my $book = {
    author  => "Fred Flinstone",
    name    => "My Favorite Stones",
    pages   => [
        {
            number  => 1,
            footer  => "Dedicated to Wilma",
            lines   => [ ],
        },
        {
            number  => 2,
            lines   => [
                { text => "Preface", style => "h1" },
                { text => "This book is about my favorite stones:" },
                { text => "Marble" },
                # ...
            ]
        },
        # ...
    ]
};
```

Should there be one smart pair of methods in Book that knows about all member classes?  Or should each class implement part of it so that e.g. `Line::save` returned something like `{ text => "Marble" }`?

What is the *correct* way to implement this?  I would like solution that is as least as possible bounded to the actual data.  What if I decide tomorrow to add `Page::bookmarks` and want to save `Bookmark`s as well?

Oh, and I'm using Moose, although that should not make much difference.

Comment: You can serialize and restore blessed objects with `Storable` module.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Moose, I would recommend looking at [MooseX::Storage](https://metacpan.org/module/MooseX%3a%3aStorage) to handle this. You would use this module inside your package then add `with Storage('format' => 'YAML', 'io' => 'File');`.

This quick example may get you started:

```
package Book;
use Moose;
use MooseX::Storage;

with Storage('format' => 'YAML', 'io' => 'File');

...

1;

my $book = Book->new();

...

# to store object
$book->store('book.yml');

# to get object back
my $book2 = Book->load('book.yml');
```